Grid based image transformation resulting in mirrored / reversed image
I am trying to take an image of a rug that has been shot on the floor at an angle, I then create a grid , equally distanced, for all points of the rug. The grid creation is like this

The grid points are stored clockwise, so top left corner, top right, bottom right and then bottom left corner.
Then I am trying to use the below code to grid by grid transform this image into a straight rug.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from final.mesh import create_mesh_points
import csv

def generate_destination_mesh(target_size, num_divisions):
    target_width, target_height = target_size

    # Using integer division for cells; the last division might be slightly larger to cover the whole image
    cell_width = target_width // (num_divisions - 1)
    cell_height = target_height // (num_divisions - 1)

    extra_width = target_width % (num_divisions - 1)
    extra_height = target_height % (num_divisions - 1)

    dst_points = np.zeros((num_divisions, num_divisions, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    
    for i in range(num_divisions):
        for j in range(num_divisions):
            x = j * cell_width if j < num_divisions - 1 else j * cell_width + extra_width
            y = i * cell_height if i < num_divisions - 1 else i * cell_height + extra_height
            dst_points[i, j] = [x, y]
            
    
    return dst_points


def transform_rug(image, mesh_points, num_divisions, target_size, dst_mesh_points, csv_filename):
    target_width, target_height = target_size
    transformed_rug = np.zeros((target_height, target_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Cell Index i', 'Cell Index j', 'Source Points', 'Destination Points'])

        for i in range(49):
            for j in range(49):
                src_points = np.array([
                    mesh_points[i][j],       # Top-left
                    mesh_points[i][j+1],   # Top-right
                    mesh_points[i + 1][j + 1],  # Bottom-right
                    mesh_points[i+1][j]    # Bottom-left
                ], dtype=np.float32)

                dst_points = np.array([
                    dst_mesh_points[i][j],       # Top-left
                    dst_mesh_points[i][j + 1],   # Top-right
                    dst_mesh_points[i + 1][j + 1],  # Bottom-right
                    dst_mesh_points[i + 1][j]    # Bottom-left
                ], dtype=np.float32)

                
                matrix, _ = cv2.findHomography(src_points, dst_points)
                warped_cell = cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (target_width, target_height))

                # Place the warped cell into the correct position of the transformed rug ## Harcoding below to troubleshoot
                start_y = i * target_height // num_divisions
                end_y = (i + 1) * target_height // num_divisions
                start_x = j * target_width // num_divisions
                end_x = (j + 1) * target_width // num_divisions
                transformed_rug[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x] = warped_cell[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x]

                writer.writerow([i, j, src_points.tolist(), dst_points.tolist(), start_x,start_y,end_x,end_y])


    return transformed_rug



# Load your original rug image
source_image_path = 'images/marked.png'
original_rug = cv2.imread(source_image_path)

# Set the number of divisions in your grid
num_divisions = 50  # Change this based on your actual divisions

mesh_points = create_mesh_points(source_image_path,num_divisions)
csv_filename = 'grid_points.csv'

# Set your target size (width, height)
target_size = (1800, 2700)  # Adjust as per your actual needs

# Generate the destination mesh
destination_mesh_points = generate_destination_mesh(target_size, num_divisions)


# Transform the rug
final_rug = transform_rug(original_rug, mesh_points, num_divisions, target_size,destination_mesh_points, csv_filename)

# Save or display the final transformed rug
#cv2.imshow('Transformed Rug', final_rug)
cv2.imwrite('transformed.png', final_rug)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()

These are the first 5 values of my source grid, destination grid and the XY co-ordinates of where the cell is top be placed



Cell Index i
Cell Index j
Source Points
Destination Points
Start X
Start Y
End X
End Y




0
0
[[1675.0, 99.0], [1705.0, 91.0], [1686.0, 155.0], [1656.0, 161.0]]
[[0.0, 0.0], [36.0, 0.0], [36.0, 55.0], [0.0, 55.0]]
0
0
36
54


0
1
[[1656.0, 161.0], [1686.0, 155.0], [1666.0, 215.0], [1637.0, 222.0]]
[[36.0, 0.0], [72.0, 0.0], [72.0, 55.0], [36.0, 55.0]]
36
0
72
54


0
2
[[1637.0, 222.0], [1666.0, 215.0], [1645.0, 276.0], [1617.0, 284.0]]
[[72.0, 0.0], [108.0, 0.0], [108.0, 55.0], [72.0, 55.0]]
72
0
108
54


0
3
[[1617.0, 284.0], [1645.0, 276.0], [1623.0, 335.0], [1595.0, 344.0]]
[[108.0, 0.0], [144.0, 0.0], [144.0, 55.0], [108.0, 55.0]]
108
0
144
54


0
4
[[1595.0, 344.0], [1623.0, 335.0], [1601.0, 395.0], [1572.0, 405.0]]
[[144.0, 0.0], [180.0, 0.0], [180.0, 55.0], [144.0, 55.0]]
144
0
180
54



The output image I am getting is like this

My original input image is

You can see I have marked the corners 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 in red and those numbers are misplaced. The image seems mirrored and reversed.
I am totally lost and unable to figure out what it is that I am doing wrong. It has to be a very small mistake somewhere but I just am not able to find it out. I have gone through the grid points in the csv (sample above in the table) row by row and they all appear correct to me - how I imagine they should be.
Maybe a fresh set of eyes could help. I would appreciate a lot if someone can review my code and see if anything obvious pops out that I might be missing.
Thanks
Edit : Dated 18th May
In response to @anmabe's comment, the code I am using to create the mesh is below. I have a dilation of 0 in this code, but I will be dilating around 40 so that 0-255 alpha value pixels around the edges get included.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sourceSidePoints import process_image_and_get_side_points

def create_mesh_points(source_image_path, num_divisions, dilation=40):
    # Load image and side points
    side_points, img_with_corners = process_image_and_get_side_points(source_image_path,num_divisions)

    # Reverse points where necessary
    side_points[2] = side_points[2][::-1]  # Reverse bottom side points
    side_points[3] = side_points[3][::-1]  # Reverse left side points

    def adjust_boundaries(side_points, dilation):
        # Adjusting top side (Subtract from y)
        top = np.array([[x, y - dilation] for x, y in side_points[0]])

        # Adjusting bottom side (Add to y)
        bottom = np.array([[x, y + dilation] for x, y in side_points[2]])

        # Adjusting right side (Add to x)
        right = np.array([[x + dilation, y] for x, y in side_points[1]])

        # Adjusting left side (Subtract from x)
        left = np.array([[x - dilation, y] for x, y in side_points[3]])

        return [top, right, bottom, left]

    # Apply the dilation to the side points
    adjusted_side_points = adjust_boundaries(side_points, dilation)

    # Assigning points to variables for clarity
    top = adjusted_side_points[0]
    right = adjusted_side_points[1]
    bottom = adjusted_side_points[2]
    left = adjusted_side_points[3]

    # Assuming mesh_points is a 2D array of coordinates [num_divisions][num_divisions]
    mesh_points = np.zeros((num_divisions, num_divisions, 2), dtype=int)

    # Create the mesh by directly using the points provided
    for i in range(num_divisions):
        for j in range(num_divisions):
            # Assign boundary points directly to ensure they remain on the edges
            if i == 0:
                mesh_points[i][j] = left[j]  # First column from left

            elif i == num_divisions - 1:
                mesh_points[i][j] = right[j]  # Last column from right

            elif j == 0:
                mesh_points[i][j] = top[i]  # First row from top

            elif j == num_divisions - 1:
                mesh_points[i][j] = bottom[i]  # Last row from bottom

            else:
                # Calculate interior mesh points
                horizontal_point = (left[j] * (num_divisions - i) / num_divisions) + (right[j] * i / num_divisions)
                vertical_point = (top[i] * (num_divisions - j) / num_divisions) + (bottom[i] * j / num_divisions)
                mesh_point = (horizontal_point + vertical_point) / 2
                mesh_points[i][j] = mesh_point

    return mesh_points

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_image_path = '../images/marked.png'
       # Drawing lines and circles
    img_with_corners = cv2.imread(source_image_path)
    num_divisions = 50
    mesh_points = create_mesh_points(source_image_path, num_divisions)
    

 

    # Drawing the horizontal lines for every row
    for i in range(num_divisions):
        for j in range(num_divisions - 1):
            start_point = tuple(np.round(mesh_points[i][j]).astype(int))
            end_point = tuple(np.round(mesh_points[i][j + 1]).astype(int))
            cv2.line(img_with_corners, start_point, end_point, (255, 0, 0, 255), 3)

    # Drawing the vertical lines for every column
    for j in range(num_divisions):
        for i in range(num_divisions - 1):
            start_point = tuple(np.round(mesh_points[i][j]).astype(int))
            end_point = tuple(np.round(mesh_points[i + 1][j]).astype(int))
            cv2.line(img_with_corners, start_point, end_point, (255, 0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow('Mesh Overlay', img_with_corners)
    cv2.imwrite('mesh2.png', img_with_corners)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I found out this wonderful thing called shepards distortion from imagemagick and using that I am now able to correct my image. I have another question about making my results better, but I will be posting that as a separate question so as not to clutter this thread.
But if we can somehow make this above approach work, that will be better as we have more control in this case.

reduce the problem to a single quad. that'll help you see what's going on.

Thanks. I tried that (i=0 and j=0) and the 1st quad (top left) transforms correctly.
But then I tried with (i=10 and j=10) and again everything is mirrored/reversed
So at least now we know that the issue is somewhat related to how we are placing them after transformation (right?)
I guess its back to debugging with the co-ordinates for source, destination and placement to see where the mismatch is

I don't mean select one of the little quads. I mean make a huge one so you can see what's going on. -- yes, it might be a matter of how you place your vertices and how you define your triangles

Hi! Would it be possible for you to attach the code for final.mesh? That would help us reproduce your problem an play around with your code to find the issue.

@anmabe - Hi, I have edited my original post to include the mesh creation code
